# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: ssh, rhel, configuration, tty

I'm trying to set up automatic SSH hopping through a server which doesn't have nc.

This works from the command line:

```
ssh -A gateway ssh steve@target
```

(I have added my public key to the SSH agent).

However, adding it to ~/.ssh/config doesn't:

```
Host target
  User steveb
  ProxyCommand ssh -A gateway ssh steve@targetip

$ ssh target
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.


^CKilled by signal 2.
```

Attempting to force the issue with `-t` is amusing but unhelpful.

```
ProxyCommand ssh -A -t gateway ssh steve@targetip

$ ssh target
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.


^CKilled by signal 2.
```

More `-t`'s? No good.

```
ProxyCommand ssh -A -t -t gateway ssh steve@targetip

$ ssh target
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device


^CKilled by signal 2.
```

Is this possible? Most tutorials (eg http://www.arrfab.net/blog/?p=246 ) suggest using `nc`.

Comment: Is the conclusion that netcat is required?

Comment: Looks like it. In this instance, I was able to get it installed, solving my problem - but I don't always have that luxury.

Comment: See my answer below for two ways I was able to do this without netcat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### SSH ProxyCommand without netcat

The ProxyCommand is very useful when hosts are only indirectly accessible. With netcat it is relative strait forward:

```
ProxyCommand ssh {gw} netcat -w 1 {host} 22
```

Here {gw }and {host} are placeholders for the gateway and the host.

But it is also possible when netcat is not installed on the gateway:

```
ProxyCommand ssh {gw} 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/{host}/22; cat <&3 & cat >&3;kill $!'
```

The /dev/tcp is a built-in feature of standard bash. The files don't exist. To check whether bash has this feature built-in use run:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/google.com/80
```

...on the gateway.

To make sure that bash is used, use:

```
ProxyCommand ssh {gw} "/bin/bash -c 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/{host}/22; cat <&3 & cat >&3;kill $!'"
```

And it even works together with ControlMaster.

(Updated on Oct 22 to include kill to clean up background cat)
(Updated on Mar 3 2011 to make placeholders more clear and explain /dev/tcp)

100% credit to roland schulz. Here's the source:
http://www.rschulz.eu/2008/09/ssh-proxycommand-without-netcat.html
see more useful info in the comments there.

There is also more here:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-tcpip-access-using-bash
http://securityreliks.securegossip.com/2010/08/enabling-devtcp-on-backtrack-4r1ubuntu/

**UPDATE**: here's something new from [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12779/marco)

In reference to a ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config where one has a line like this:

```
ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc localhost %p
```

Marco says:

> You don't need netcat if you use a recent version of OpenSSH. You can replace nc localhost %p with -W localhost:%p.

The result would look like this:

```
ProxyCommand ssh gateway -W localhost:%p
```

Answer (score 9):

Big T, not little t.

```
-T' Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
-t' Force pseudo-tty allocation.
```

My script used to return that message, and does no longer.

```
/usr/bin/ssh -T -q -i $HOME/.ssh/one_command other_system
```

I use the `authorized_key` on the other_system to cause this to run a command:

```
from="my.mydomain.com",command="bin/remotely-run" ssh-rsa ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -A -t gateway ssh -t steve@targetip
```

Comment: Wait, how's that different from what I've tried?

Comment: @SteveBennett The difference is that this does not only try to allocate a TTY on the second system but on the first, too.

Comment: it's exactly the same command I mentioned with the "amusing but unhelpful" result?

Comment: @SteveBennett I misread that, indeed. My aim was to have the `-t` in both connections and I saw it in the wrong one. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah. Well, still no good. Tried all the combinations.

Answer (score -3):

You could try the following technique of ssh'ing into server1 followed by ssh'ing into server2.

```
$ ssh -t user1@server1 ssh -t user2@server2
```

Doing it like this works for me.

Comment: Please explain more... What this command does and how it is useful to solve the answer.