# one IP several guests same port 22

Tags: ssh

I use Nginx to redirect my domains coming on port 80 to the correct virtual machines, now I'm wondering if I can do this with ssh on port 22. Redirect all ssh traffic to the correct guests through port 22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It works for HTTP, because the protocol supports [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html). SSH doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this through ssh's `ProxyCommand` facility. Add the following to your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file. Create it if it doesn't exist with just this content:

```
Host remoteserverX
    User userint
    ProxyCommand ssh userext@externalserver nc remoteserverX %p
Host remoteserverY
    User userint
    ProxyCommand ssh userext@externalserver nc remoteserverY %p
```

You then connect to the different internal remote servers like this:

```
$ ssh remoteserverX

-or-

$ ssh remoteserverY
```

This is the tip of the iceberg as far as this feature goes. Check out this U&L Q&A titled: [SSH tunnel through middleman server - how to connect in one step (using key pair)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/ssh-tunnel-through-middleman-server-how-to-connect-in-one-step-using-key-pair), for more details.

**NOTE:** The above method is making use of a tool called `nc` (netcat) which should be in any major distros' repositories.

This isn't exactly the same as Nginx's redirection, you're tunneling through the external system to get to the internal system, but it has a similar effect.

#### Complex examples

1. One `Host` stanza, many hosts.

   ```
   Host *.mydom.com *
       ProxyCommand ssh externalserver nc %h %p
   ```
2. One `Hosts stanza, for many users.

   Add the `Hosts` stanza to the system's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file so that anyone logging into the box can make use of it.

Comment: this is not practical for each user to have to do

Comment: @yakamok - as I said this is the tip of the iceberg. You can make a more general rule that acts as a template so you can get into any system behind the main system.