# VM with NGINX as SSH proxy for the other guest VM's

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, nginx, proxy

I have some Ubuntu Virtual Box VM guests on an OSX host. I want to SSH into these guests through the internet. I want to set up one VM with NGINX as SSH proxy for the other guest VM's. The other guests are not websites, they only have IP-addresses or maybe VirtualBox id's.
What Virtual Box network settings are required for this or what is the recommended setup? Should I enable OpenSSH on the proxy and the other VM's? Or where should the certbot certs etc. go?
I have read [this (old) question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86219/one-ip-several-guests-same-port-22) but I am not that far yet. I also hope I won't need to experiment because NGINX is complex.

Actually, I might as well directly SSH into the other VM's but then they would have to capture different ports in bridged mode, wouldn't they?

Actually, at the moment I only need LAN access (to work from my bed), so putting an additional guest in bridged mode and using this guest's local IP suffices.

I changed the OpenSSH port in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but didn't restart OpenSSH daemon yet. I opened an extra port on my router, put the guest VBox in bridged mode and let openSSH listen on the extra port. I hope the additional bridged guest does not steal all traffic from the NGINX web server guest, and I can ssh to the extra port and be connected to the extra guest straight away. However, bridged mode is not optimal, I think Internal would suffice and be safer. I do use SSH keys on top of the password. I think using SSH via the web proxy allows me to monitor the traffic on that proxy. Furthermore some of the other guests do run web applications behind their own NGINX proxies. I could additionally use OpenSSH on them and direct traffic with router port forwarding. The (I think better) alternative is to use the NGINX proxy.

Comment: It's possible, see [nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/blog/running-non-ssl-protocols-over-ssl-port-nginx-1-15-2/), [nginx.org](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html#example) - the question is why. The example given pretty much has the purpose of poking through firewalls (secretly run SSH over HTTPS port). As for using multiple ports, you'd have to do that with nginx too, if you have more than a single VM / SSH target. Since there is no vhost/subdomain functionality. That or you give each a dedicated IPv6 address on your router VM...