# One liner to ssh into a server, specifying an intermediary to tunnel through

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ssh-tunneling

At my company, In order to SSH into anything, I first have to SSH into an intermediary server like so:

(me@local.machine) ssh intermediary.server.com

(me@intermediary.server.com) ssh application.server.com

(root@application.server.com) *this is the command prompt I want to be at*

I would like to make a bash alias, so that I can run a single command on my local machine and get dropped into the desired machine's "command prompt".

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have `netcat` or `nc` installed on the bastion host?

Comment: You can use the `ProxyCommand` in your local `~/.ssh/config` to hop to remote from intermediary: `Host remote\n ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p intermediary`

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/ssh-tunnel-through-middleman-server-how-to-connect-in-one-step-using-key-pair regarding using netcat on the intermediary server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
alias cmdname="ssh -t me@intermediary.server.com ssh application.server.com"
```

From `man ssh`:

```
  -t     Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
         trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g., when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Source the file to pickup the new alias:

```
source .bashrc [OR] source .bash_profile
```

Test it out now from terminal:

```
[user]# cmdname
```

If you don't already I would also setup ssh-keys so that you don't need to enter any passwords. You just enter the command and are auto-logged in.

Comment: Thank you, this command is fantastic!