# Using reverse SSH tunneling in one step instead of two steps (with -X)

Tags: bash, ssh, x11, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

Suppose we have three hosts:

- `miki` - my computer behind a NAT
- `vps0` - my VPS
- `mum` - computer of my mother, behind a different  NAT.

The task is to connect from my computer to my mum and keep X11 forwarding.
Until now I used reverse tunneling like below:

```
# on mum's computer (at crontab on reboot):
autossh -fN -M 3986 -R 1993:localhost:22 login@vps0

# when I want to connect to mum's computer
miki$ ssh login@vps0
vps0$ ssh localhost -p 1993
```

Presented above approach, has a disadvantage that I can't use X11 forwarding (-X parameter) - I can't open windows remotely.

I am wondering if is it possible to connect directly to my mum's computer and keep X11 forwarding.

PS. I sow answers in topic: [SSH tunnel through middleman server - how to connect in one step (using key pair)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82269/ssh-tunnel-through-middleman-server-how-to-connect-in-one-step-using-key-pair). Unfortunately using that solutions causes that X11 forwarding doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Why doesn't that solution with `ProxyCommand` work for X11 forwarding?  I think you can directly reach mum's computer with X11 forwarding using the following configuration.

```
Host mum
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W localhost:1993 login@vps0
ForwardX11 yes
```

Answer (score 2):

If you understand what is going on in X11 forwarding, you will know that it is not so simple as described in the answer from @yaegashi. X11 forwarding is creating another layer under the ssh and it can't be chained as normal terminal data streams. But you are able to do it using port forwarding:

Based on this [blog post](http://hugoideler.com/2012/08/multi-hop-x-forwarding-over-ssh/), which does it as hardcoding in shell script. I was trying to do the same using `ssh_config`, but without any success. You just need to add complexity of the reverse tunnel the the original script

```
sshx () {
    # create the tunnel from vps0 to your host
    sudo ssh -Nn vps0 -L 3991:vps0:1993 &
    sleep 1s
    PID=$!
    # connect to localhost on forwrded port
    ssh localhost -XYC -p3991
    sudo kill $PID
}
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: I believe it's so simple as described in my answer in this case.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Yup.  I regularly use multi-hop ssh with `ProxyCommand` and `ForwardX11` to connect remote hosts behind router and invoke X11 apps there.  Simple chain of `ssh -X` should also work, OP can do `ssh -X login@vps0` followed by `ssh -X localhost -p 1993` and have correct `$DISPLAY` on mum's computer.